# Subsets confusion

Tags: real-analysis

It states in my notes on compactness that $(a,+\infty) \subseteq \bigcup_n (a,a+n)$, which I am rather confused by. Does this mean we let $n$ go negative as well as postiive to make the RHS larger than  $(a,+\infty)$ ?

Comment: No they probably mean $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it $n$ be quantified $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The notation would be $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}$, so no, it is not necessary to use an additional quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like "$\leq$", the "$\subseteq$" relationship is reflexive: for any $A$ we have $A\subseteq A$.  So the fact that the RHS is the same as the LHS is not a problem.

Many people use "$\subset$" rather than "$\subseteq$".  They mean the same thing, and both symbols are just referred as "subset".  That said, I tend to prefer "$\subseteq$", so as to avoid ambiguity.  If I want to refer to strict inclusion, I'll use "$\subsetneq$".

---

If that isn't what you were asking, then please read on:

To show that $U\subseteq V$, all you need to show is that every element $u\in U$ is an element of $V$.

In this this case, pick an element $u\in (a,\infty)$, and let $m$ be some positive integer greater than $u-a$.   Then this $u$ is clearly an element of $(a,a+m)$, and so is an element of the union $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a,a+n).$$  The fact that $(a,\infty)$ is not a subset of any individual $(a,a+n)$ is neither here nor there.